# How to capture this specific string using regular in shell?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a text:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| ID                                   |
+--------------------------------------+
| cb91a52f-f0dd-443a-adfe-84c5c685d9b3 |
| 184564aa-9a7d-48ef-b8f0-ff9d51987e71 |
| f01f9739-c7a7-404c-8789-4e3e2edf314e |
| 825925cc-a816-4434-8b4b-a75301ddaefd |
| 5b1b0ec1-9c7e-4852-bbb7-b1c883c2acce |
| fec4a447-9f51-4796-9c92-42268cd21ad1 |
| 77b37392-c5f8-4537-8e2b-971f6b161dec |
| e8524cf0-47d4-43f8-aee3-2af03f511ebe |
| 2a6640e2-bfdf-416c-8d86-e2127802779a |
| 0223ac3d-2f99-42ab-b6be-cc738e5e3e25 |
| d3577eb1-c8cb-4328-bf5f-48cb2ef43229 |
| f46ed4c1-9325-4d35-8dda-18d2af31a510 |
| 311bc474-5747-4408-9124-6fa3a24c08c1 |
| 81ebddc6-612f-4675-9004-80c35207e1e3 |
| 09518994-7b37-481c-b058-d74c16d4c198 |
| 1e318d02-afd4-4b97-85d8-8c8f8b007144 |
| c220fae1-5a56-485f-ad51-0e0316bc105c |
| afbef917-2ee8-4eb9-948d-48fcd5ffc6e4 |
| cc8a6692-2ba9-4203-bf50-b02a8e4a0f21 |
| f49089be-4b2a-4b10-bfbd-495001e64f54 |
| d89b0b19-0f26-4b9a-8a9a-25a41f59cee5 |
| 18f1717f-74ac-429a-ba2b-4466489a2558 |
| 7560d8b2-3e3d-474c-bcf8-ded378d50954 |
| 1b02c8f9-6077-4499-93f6-bc04d8b0ca3a |
| 9ca256b4-c9eb-4a60-8fb5-dfe4ea883e1f |
| 3c837469-aa82-41ac-b75e-9bb087501789 |
| e151d2c7-5360-466c-857f-7474eec4eaeb |
| c7ca1066-c077-4846-aae0-56d7fc63c32d |
| 034026df-9e45-49e1-ab41-0ad3f4e5e33b |
| 45bb533d-ff92-419e-8523-bb4c9889a04e |
+--------------------------------------+
**** Total: 30 ****
```

I want to catch lines like this:

```
| cb91a52f-f0dd-443a-adfe-84c5c685d9b3 |
```

which is "| **UUID** |"

So I use regular like this:

```
check_vm_connectivity()
{
    res=`cat temp.txt` # this got text above
    re='^\| [a-z0-9\-]+ \|'

    for line in "$res"
    do
        if [[ "${line}" =~ $re ]] ; then
            echo "${line}"
        fi
    done
}
```

`^\| [a-z0-9\-]+ \|` is the regular I use, but the result capture all lines, I don't know what's wrong? Is that because I should change ' into "?

Comment: What is unique about the line you are capturing? How should it be identified?

Comment: The line I want to capture is : "| UUID |". So I use the regular like this, but there are some wrong, I don't know why...

Comment: What is `UUID`, how is the expected output match to it? It is still not clear

Comment: what is $re ???

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: `for var in [something]` does not split by lines. See [BashFAQ #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the following command be what you are looking for:

```
grep -oP "^\|\s*\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}\s*\|$" input.file | grep -v '_'
```

**OUTPUT** on your input file:

```
| cb91a52f-f0dd-443a-adfe-84c5c685d9b3 |
| 184564aa-9a7d-48ef-b8f0-ff9d51987e71 |
| f01f9739-c7a7-404c-8789-4e3e2edf314e |
| 825925cc-a816-4434-8b4b-a75301ddaefd |
| 5b1b0ec1-9c7e-4852-bbb7-b1c883c2acce |
| fec4a447-9f51-4796-9c92-42268cd21ad1 |
| 77b37392-c5f8-4537-8e2b-971f6b161dec |
| e8524cf0-47d4-43f8-aee3-2af03f511ebe |
| 2a6640e2-bfdf-416c-8d86-e2127802779a |
| 0223ac3d-2f99-42ab-b6be-cc738e5e3e25 |
| d3577eb1-c8cb-4328-bf5f-48cb2ef43229 |
| f46ed4c1-9325-4d35-8dda-18d2af31a510 |
| 311bc474-5747-4408-9124-6fa3a24c08c1 |
| 81ebddc6-612f-4675-9004-80c35207e1e3 |
| 09518994-7b37-481c-b058-d74c16d4c198 |
| 1e318d02-afd4-4b97-85d8-8c8f8b007144 |
| c220fae1-5a56-485f-ad51-0e0316bc105c |
| afbef917-2ee8-4eb9-948d-48fcd5ffc6e4 |
| cc8a6692-2ba9-4203-bf50-b02a8e4a0f21 |
| f49089be-4b2a-4b10-bfbd-495001e64f54 |
| d89b0b19-0f26-4b9a-8a9a-25a41f59cee5 |
| 18f1717f-74ac-429a-ba2b-4466489a2558 |
| 7560d8b2-3e3d-474c-bcf8-ded378d50954 |
| 1b02c8f9-6077-4499-93f6-bc04d8b0ca3a |
| 9ca256b4-c9eb-4a60-8fb5-dfe4ea883e1f |
| 3c837469-aa82-41ac-b75e-9bb087501789 |
| e151d2c7-5360-466c-857f-7474eec4eaeb |
| c7ca1066-c077-4846-aae0-56d7fc63c32d |
| 034026df-9e45-49e1-ab41-0ad3f4e5e33b |
| 45bb533d-ff92-419e-8523-bb4c9889a04e |
```

**Explanations:**

- `^` beginning of line
- `\|` match `|` literally
- `\s*` followed by 0 to N space char
- `\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}` where `\w` is a word char number, digit or underscore, `\w{8}` the 8 means appearing exactly 8 times, `{12}` means appearing exactly 12 times, ...
- `\s*` followed by 0 to N space char
- `\|` match `|` literally
- `$` for the end of line

Then just in case I pipe to | `grep -v '_'` to remove lines with `_` this might not be necessary if you are confident that the lines will not contain those one.

If you want to extract the `UUID` you can use the following grep command:

```
grep -oP "(?<=^\|\s)\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}(?=\s\|$)" input.file | grep -v '_'                                                        
cb91a52f-f0dd-443a-adfe-84c5c685d9b3
184564aa-9a7d-48ef-b8f0-ff9d51987e71
f01f9739-c7a7-404c-8789-4e3e2edf314e
825925cc-a816-4434-8b4b-a75301ddaefd
5b1b0ec1-9c7e-4852-bbb7-b1c883c2acce
fec4a447-9f51-4796-9c92-42268cd21ad1
77b37392-c5f8-4537-8e2b-971f6b161dec
e8524cf0-47d4-43f8-aee3-2af03f511ebe
2a6640e2-bfdf-416c-8d86-e2127802779a
0223ac3d-2f99-42ab-b6be-cc738e5e3e25
d3577eb1-c8cb-4328-bf5f-48cb2ef43229
f46ed4c1-9325-4d35-8dda-18d2af31a510
311bc474-5747-4408-9124-6fa3a24c08c1
81ebddc6-612f-4675-9004-80c35207e1e3
09518994-7b37-481c-b058-d74c16d4c198
1e318d02-afd4-4b97-85d8-8c8f8b007144
c220fae1-5a56-485f-ad51-0e0316bc105c
afbef917-2ee8-4eb9-948d-48fcd5ffc6e4
cc8a6692-2ba9-4203-bf50-b02a8e4a0f21
f49089be-4b2a-4b10-bfbd-495001e64f54
d89b0b19-0f26-4b9a-8a9a-25a41f59cee5
18f1717f-74ac-429a-ba2b-4466489a2558
7560d8b2-3e3d-474c-bcf8-ded378d50954
1b02c8f9-6077-4499-93f6-bc04d8b0ca3a
9ca256b4-c9eb-4a60-8fb5-dfe4ea883e1f
3c837469-aa82-41ac-b75e-9bb087501789
e151d2c7-5360-466c-857f-7474eec4eaeb
c7ca1066-c077-4846-aae0-56d7fc63c32d
034026df-9e45-49e1-ab41-0ad3f4e5e33b
45bb533d-ff92-419e-8523-bb4c9889a04e
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression `re='^\| [a-z0-9\-]+ \|'` is fine, the problem in your code is with the for loop going through it line by line.

```
for line in "$res"
```

That executes the loop only once, with the whole contents of `$res` inside `$line`.

This should fix it:

```
check_vm_connectivity() {
  local re='^\| [a-z0-9\-]+ \|'
  local line

  while read line ; do
    if [[ "${line}" =~ $re ]] ; then
      echo "${line}"
    fi
  done <temp.txt
}
```